# How to set new function parameters for Onclick inside itself

Tags: javascript, html

I'm tying to create a class of html buttons that have a parameterized onclick event handler attached to them. Every time an instance of this button is pressed it should set new parameters for the next click.
For example when the page is loaded, the onclick is like

```js
onclick="Load([a, b, c, d, e])";
```

and when you click on it Load function is executed and then new values for onclick parameters are assigned (with some specific logic) like

```js
onclick="Load([b, a, c, e, d])";
```

I have a number of these buttons in a page that a click on each should just change that single button's handler. Can I change these at the end of Load function itself? How can I do this assignment?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <script>
     var arr=[a, b, c, d, e];
     function Load(arg)
     {
      //Code which uses arg....
      // After this, change the arr
      arr=[b, a, c, e, d]; //or something like that
     }
   </script>
</head>

<body>
   <div onclick="Load(arr);"></div>
   <div onclick="Load(arr);"></div> <!-- This time, [b, a, c, e, d] will be passed. -->
</body>
```

Comment: These buttons are generated dynamically which means I don't know how many they are. So I can't (and don't want to) store a parameters array for each. Instead I'm looking for some real-time solution inside function for the single button that has caused this handler function's execution.

Answer (score -1):

If you add the `onclick` attribute to the button itself, you can have your Javascript use the `id` of that field and change the value of the `onClick` attribute